# C++ Error - expected primary-expression before '.' token| IN STRUCTURE

Tags: c++, structure

I just want to say that i am still learning C++ so I started with the module about Structures, and While I do not understand everything, I think I got it somewhat right. The error the compiler keeps giving me is :

error: expected primary-expression before '.' token|

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct catalog
{
    char title[50];
    char author[50];
    char publisher[30];
    int yearpublish;
    double price;
};

int main()
{
    catalog book;
    char again;

    fstream fbook;
    fbook.open("book.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);

    do
    {
        //Read data about the book
        cout << "Enter the following data about a book:\n";
        cout << "Title:";
        cin.getline (book.title,50);
        cout << "Author:";
        cin.getline (book.author,50);
        cout << "Publisher name:";
        cin.getline (book.publisher,30);
        cout << "Year publish:";
        cin >> book.yearpublish;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Price:";
        cin >> book.price;
        cin.ignore();

        //write the contents to the binary file
        fbook.write((char*)&catalog , sizeof(book));

        cout << "Do you want to enter another record?(Y/N)";
        cin >> again;
        cin.ignore();
    } while (again == 'Y' || again == 'y');

    fbook.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Please Help.

Comment: On which line are you seeing the error?

Answer (score 5):

what are you doing here in this line

```
fbook.write((char*)&catalog , sizeof(book));
```

I think it should be

```
 fbook.write((char*)&book , sizeof(book));
```